# Easiest way to set up a shortcut to mute volume?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, audio

I'm found no way via command prompt for some silly reason...
My current solution of a small c# program pinvoking [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) (in user32.dll) I feel isn't quite the best way of going about making a shortcut to mute the volume on vista, but I have yet to find a simple solution.

Comment: I also had to resort to a writing a custom app to mute or change my volume by command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://help.wugnet.com/windows/turn-sound-script-batch-file-WinXP-Home-P3-ftopict633244.html):

> Using VBscript you can control the master volume Mute with the following:
>
> Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
>   WshShell.SendKeys(chr(173))
>
> or (using Hex values)
>
> Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
>   WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAD))
>
> This sends the keycode value used by multimedia keyboards and is a toggle.

Just save it as a .vbs file and set up a shortcut to that file.